# Plants Fungus Infection

Tags: diseases, tomatoes, container-gardening

I am new to garden and I have a tomato plant that is infected by fungus.

I would like to ask how fungus infects the plant? Does the disease affect the soil, plant or both?

Comment: That's going to be heavily dependent on which fungus you have. If you have pictures upload them. If you know the name of the fungus, that will help too.

Comment: What type of fungal infection? You used the [tag:container-gardening] tag -- does that mean the plant is growing in a pot? If so, what kind of growing medium do you have in it?

Comment: And where are you in the world please?

Comment: Please post a picture of the plant (with closeups of the infections), and add some more detail to your question. That way we can give you a much better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I grow plants in pots and the temperature is around 30 Degrees.

I am referring to early blight, black spots, and septoria.

Comment: *How* the different fungi affect the plant is not in our scope at this site. You could ask that at http://biology.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yup, first thing is to identify the disease...FOR SURE.  This is heavily dependent on pictures, close ups as well as of the soil and the entire plant(s).  Why are you saying blight?  And what kind of soil DID YOU USE if these plants are in pots?  Bagged or garden??  30 degrees (F or C)?  If it is a fungus, the usual entry is by water splashing off the soil, picking up spores and landing on the leaves.  With blight, the entire plant becomes infected, leaves, stems and fruit.  With spot, the plant actually kills the cells that have been infected, they blacken and then drop out...